# When is $Ind(\mathcal{C})$ equivalent to $PSh(\mathcal{C})$?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category. We know that every presheaf $\mathcal{C}^{op} \to Set$ is a colimit over its slice category of representable functors. I'm wondering when every such colimit is a directed limit, and thus when the category $Ind(\mathcal{C})$ is equivalent to the category of presheaves on $\mathcal{C}$.

My idea for a sufficient condition: If $\mathcal{C}$ is small and has coproducts, then every colimit is directed. This is pretty obvious, since the coproduct of two objects provides the upper bound in the slice category of a presheaf, thus making it a directed set (it's a set by smallness of $\mathcal{C}$).

Is my argument correct that this is a sufficient condition for $Ind(\mathcal{C}) \cong PSh(\mathcal{C})$? If not, are there any other necessary and sufficient conditions for this to be the case?

Comment: If $C$ is small and has coproducts, then it's a preorder by Freyd's theorem.

Comment: Wouldn't it have upper bounds as well? For any objects $A$ and $B$ you have $A \to A \coprod B$ and $B \to A \coprod B$.

Comment: Okay I realized this is false. The category of finitely generated projective modules over a ring $R$ is essentially small with finite coproducts but the ind category is all modules

Comment: The ind category is flat modules.

Comment: Thanks. I meant to put finitely presented modules but either way it works

Answer (score 0):

The category of presheaves on a small category $\mathcal C$ is equivalent to $\mathbf{Ind}(\mathbf{Rex}(\mathcal C))$, where $\mathbf{Rex}(\mathcal C)$ is the free finite cocompletion of $\mathcal C$. Therefore, you are asking when $\mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal C) \simeq \mathbf{Ind}(\mathbf{Rex}(\mathcal C))$, i.e. when $\mathcal C \simeq \mathbf{Rex}(\mathcal C)$, which is never true. However, if you simply want to know when $\mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal C)$ is equivalent to *some* presheaf category, for $\mathcal C$ small, then it is necessary and sufficient for $\mathcal C$ to be the finite cocompletion of a small category.